# Not able to get all open socket connections with GetTcpTable2 when executed from windows service (with SYSTEM user)

Tags: sockets, service

I'm trying get all open socket connections using GetTcpTable2 but when it is executed in windows service (with system user) it is only showing system only sockets. Is there any way we can avoid impersonation to get all open sockets along with their remote connection pid?

I'm using following code,

```
  PMIB_TCPTABLE2 TcpTable = NULL;
  ULONG TcpTableSize = 0;
  ULONG result;

  do
  {
      result = GetTcpTable2(TcpTable, &TcpTableSize, TRUE);
      if (result != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
          break;

      LocalFree(TcpTable);
      TcpTable = (PMIB_TCPTABLE2)LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, TcpTableSize);
  } while (TcpTable != NULL);
```

Comment: Sounds like `GetTcpTable2()` is limited to just the calling session only. If that is the case, you will have to make your service enumerate the active sessions (via `WTSEnumerateSessions()`) and run a new process inside each one (via `WTSQueryUserToken()` and `CreateProcessAsUser()`) to call `GetTcpTable2()` locally, and then communicate the information back to your service via an IPC mechanism, such as a named pipe.